# SSL connection alert hanshake failure

Tags: ssl, tomcat, openssl

I'm having problem establishing the connection between the client and the Server .I'm using my own signed certificate on client and on server. I'm using the SSL ciphers SSLCipherSuite ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA and some suggested that I should use the prime256v1 elliptic curves(I do not know what exactly does this means ) .I ;m using an apache tomcat server.My httpd-ssl-virtual-host-conf looks like this

ssl read bytes sslv3 alert handshake_failure

```
   Listen 4445
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

Include "conf/httpd-jk.conf"
<VirtualHost *:4445>
#General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "htdocs"
ServerName ocu1.totalsoft.ro
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
TransferLog "logs/access_log"
CustomLog logs/car2x.log combined

#JKMount  /car2x/* worker1

JKMount  /BTS/* worker1
#<Location "/car2x/WEB-INF/">

<Location "/BTS/WEB-INF/">
   deny from all
</Location>

JkMountCopy On

<Directory "htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -All +SSLv3 +TLSv1
#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
#   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
#SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+SSLv3:+TLSv1:+EXP:+eNULL
# This is only for allowed ciphers specified within the core service communication document
#SSLCipherSuite HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+TLSv1:+ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:+ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:+ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
#SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
#SSLCipherSuite AES128-SHA

#SSLCertificateFile "conf/server-cert.pem"
#SSLCertificateFile "conf/resource/server-cert.pem"
SSLCertificateFile "conf/resource/Bucharest4.pem"


#SSLCertificateFile "conf/server-dsa.crt"

#SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/server-key.pem"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/server-key.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/resource/Bucharest4_key.pem"


SSLCACertificateFile "conf/ca.pem"


SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca

#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
SSLOptions +ExportCertData
#<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
#    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
#</FilesMatch>
<Directory "cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

I'm getting the followinq error on the client side

D/https(1153): INFO TEXT: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

But when I'm trying to connect with `openssl s_client  -ciphers ECDH-ECDSA-AES-SHA -connect ocu1.totalsoft.ro -k` it works?

I can provide wireshark logs. In that logs I receive a lot of client hello but no server hello. Instead I receive `sslv3 alert with number 40 (hanshake_failure)`.

Comment: What version of openssl did you compile into your apache distribution and do you have any errors being written into your ssl_error log?

Comment: You might try to remove the ECDH ciphers when connecting with OpenSSL.
I am facing a similar issue and removing these allowed to connect.
I am still investigating the root cause.